# Git subtree installation broken on a Windows 2010 Pro install

Tags: windows, windows-10, bash, git

Something I'm unable to track down the source of my broken my Git “subtree” command. I'm running Windows 2010 Pro.

Here the error message, instead of display the help info:

```
$ git subtree
It looks like either your git installation or your
git-subtree installation is broken.

Tips:
 - If `git --exec-path` does not print the correct path to
   your git install directory, then set the GIT_EXEC_PATH
   environment variable to the correct directory.
 - Make sure that your `git-core\git-subtree` file is either in your
   PATH or in your git exec path (`C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core`).
 - You should run git-subtree as `git core\git-subtree`,
   not as `git-core\git-subtree`
```

This the output of --exec-path option:

```
$ git --exec-path
C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
```

No matter if I set the path `C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core` in `PATH` and/or `GIT_EXEC_PATH` env variable, no matter if I do it in Git Bash `.bashrc` I always get the same error message.

I tried to removed and install it again various time achieving nothing.

I tried to examine git-subtree script source, this is the code that detects the issue:

```
if test -z "$GIT_EXEC_PATH" || test "${PATH#"${GIT_EXEC_PATH}:"}" = "$PATH" || ! test -f "$GIT_EXEC_PATH/git-sh-setup"
then
    echo >&2 'It looks like either your git installation or your'
    echo >&2 'git-subtree installation is broken.'
    echo >&2
    echo >&2 "Tips:"
    echo >&2 " - If \`git --exec-path\` does not print the correct path to"
    echo >&2 "   your git install directory, then set the GIT_EXEC_PATH"
    echo >&2 "   environment variable to the correct directory."
    echo >&2 " - Make sure that your \`${0##*/}\` file is either in your"
    echo >&2 "   PATH or in your git exec path (\`$(git --exec-path)\`)."
    echo >&2 " - You should run git-subtree as \`git ${0##*/git-}\`,"
    echo >&2 "   not as \`${0##*/}\`." >&2
    exit 126
fi
```

I don't know why at least one condition is not satifisfied, why in my opinion should.

I have also made a test. If I comment the guard code about paths everything work perfectly.

Comment: I've done a test. If I comment the guard code about paths everything works perfectly.

Comment: Bold emphasis really doesn’t help make the question clearer. It is very clear as-is and hopefully someone can come along and assist you with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a bug in git@2.32 for Windows. You can check the issue [here](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3260)

> It looks like either your git installation or your git-subtree installation is broken.
>
> Tips:
>
> - If `git --exec-path` does not print the correct path to
>   your git install directory, then set the GIT_EXEC_PATH
>   environment variable to the correct directory.
> - Make sure that your `git-core\git-subtree` file is either in your
>   PATH or in your git exec path (`C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core`).
> - You should run git-subtree as `git core\git-subtree`,
>   not as `git-core\git-subtree`.

For now, you can downgrade to @2.31, e.g.:  https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.31.0.windows.1/Git-2.31.0-64-bit.exe

Comment: I have quoted the relevant information from your link, in the future, it would be appreciated if you did that yourself.

Comment: @Ramhound, okay, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This bug was fixed in the newer version [v2.32.0.windows.2](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.32.0.windows.2).

I had the same issue and a simple reinstall of the latest Git for Windows fixed it.

Comment: Finally! Thank you